# ORMLite id generate

Tags: android, ormlite

I have this object:

```
public class Set {
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "setID", generatedId = true)
    private int setID;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "setName")
    private String setName;
}
```

If I make an object like this:

```
Set newSet = new Set("name");
setDao.create(newSet);
```

And then if i make this:

```
int id = newSet.getID();
```

Will I get the set id or should I get the whole object from the database with

```
setDao.queryForEq("setName", "name");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the ORMLite documentation is pretty extensive.  If you look up [generated-id in the docs](http://ormlite.com/docs/generated-id) you'd see the following statement:

> Boolean whether the field is an auto-generated id field. Default is false. Only one field can have this set in a class. This tells the database to auto-generate a corresponding id for every row inserted. **When an object with a generated-id is created using the Dao.create() method, the database will generate an id for the row which will be returned and set in the object by the create method.**

So after you call `setDao.create(newSet)`, the `newSet` object's `setID` field will be changed with the id from the database.

Also, calling a field `setID` is a very bad pattern.  I'd recommend just use `id`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gray. This is just what I've been searching for.